# How to add Windows 10 to GRUB on Arch install With EFI?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, dual-boot

I just installed Arch Linux and with GRUB and want to add my windows 10 with EFI partition to grub.

Now I have Arch installed on the hard drive `/dev/sdc/` with a EFI system on `/dev/sdc1`. On an other hard drive I have Windows 10 installed where the efi drive is `/dev/sda1` .

I tried to follow the arch wiki but could not find out were to get the EFI system partition for the command `esp/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. Do I have to mount the windows 10 drive if yes where should I mount it to?

Answer (score 4):

Get the UUID with: `sudo grub-probe -t fs_uuid -d /dev/sda1`

and then add an entry for Windows at the end of your grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
insmod search_fs_uuid
insmod chain
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root XXXXXXXXX
chainloader (${root})/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally `grub-mkconfig` should auto-detect dual booted operating systems (via the `os-prober` utility). This, however, requires you to have the Windows drive mounted. For example, try this:

```
$ mkdir -p /mnt/windows
$ mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

It should now automatically detect your Windows installation and you should be able to boot into Windows.

Another important thing to note regarding the previous answer to this question: you should **never** manually edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, since it can easily be overwritten by tools like `grub-mkconfig` (and the syntax isn't really all that intuitive either way).

Comment: I agree with "never manually edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`", though it is OK to change it temporarily while you are troubleshooting something. Afterwards, custom entries should go to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` followed by `sudo update-grub`.